# COMO EXPORTAR LLAVES PRIMARIAS PARA HACER RELACION ENTRE TABLAS

Tags: sql-server, relaciones

Tengo una problema, necesito exportar las llaves primarias de tres tablas hacia una tabla nueva para poder relacionar dichas tres tablas, se como hacer la foranea pero ese termino exportar me confunde un poco. Espero entiendan mi pregunta.

Ahí les mando una imagen

[image: esa es mi base de datos, y necesito relacionar 3 tablas]

Comment: revisa [ask] y mejora tu publicación, añade la estrucftura de las tablas en cuestión, lo que haz tratado y los fallos especificos